# Where am I supposed to see FirePHP output?

Tags: php, firebug, firephp

I am trying out FirePHP.

I installed it and restarted Firefox, enabled Firebug for my localhost, moved the demo `oo.php` file that comes with the download into an IIS virtual directory, changed the include path, removed the `apache_request_headers()` call since I am running IIS, and the only output I see is

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   C:\Documents and Settings\georgem\My
>   Documents\projects\auctronic\FirePHPCore\FirePHP.class.php
>   on line 167 
>   Hello World

Nothing appears in the Firebug console.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**  Noticed it said that output buffering has to be enabled so I added a call to [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the top of the file...same results.

Answer (score 5):

I believe FirePHP required you install a Firefox extension (in addition to Firebug) that watches for the HTTP headers and puts them in the console.

If that isn't the problem then I'd recommend grabbing a copy of [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). It will let you view the headers of the HTTP response. The FirePHP output should be visible there. If it's not then the problem is in your server set up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of both extensions, Firebug and FirePHP - there has been some mishap lately with the most recent Firebug and older FirePHP (and yes, FirePHP requires both including the PHP on the server and installing the extension on the 'fox).
Include `fb.php`, do `ob_start()`, make up a variable of your own and then

```
fb($myErrorVariable, 'My brand new error', FirePHP::ERROR);
```

You should see the the output both in the Firebug console and under the Net tab (expand the first line relative to your script and tab to 'Server').

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that the 'Net' tab of firebug wasn't enabled caused firephp to not show anything in the console. Enabled Net tab and voila!